# Applying Filter after Fetching data from api in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, icons

I'm Fetching data from this Api https://randomuser.me/api/?results=25

I want to perform a check after getting data that if gender=Male then I want to show a Male Icon,
so how can we perform this check on Api data and return some html data like img tag or something to show icon?

Can anyone tell how can I do that?

Here is the code

```
function Users() {
 const [Users, setUsers] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=25')
        .then(Response=>{
            if(Response.data){
                alert("FOund")
                console.log(Response.data.results)
                setUsers(Response.data.results)

            }else{
                alert("not found")
            }
        })
    }, [])
    
    const displaylist = Users.map((User,index)=>{
       if(User.gender==='male'){
        return(
            

            <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td><img src={User.picture.medium}></img></td>
<td>{User.name.first}</td>
                <td>{User.name.last}</td>
                <td>{User.location.city}</td>
                <td>{User.location.state}</td>
                <td>{User.email}</td>



                
            </tr>
            

        




    
)
       }
        
    })
    const displaylistf = Users.map((User,index)=>{
        if(User.gender==='female'){
         return(
             
 
             <tr>
             <th scope="row">1</th>
                 <td><img src={User.picture.medium}></img></td>
 <td>{User.name.first}</td>
                 <td>{User.name.last}</td>
                 <td>{User.location.city}</td>
                 <td>{User.location.state}</td>
                 <td>{User.email}</td>
 
 
 
                 
             </tr>
             
 
         
 
 
 
 
     
 )
        }
         
     })
    
    return (
        <div className="user">
            <section id="admin" class=" px-2 px-md-5">
        <div class="container-fluid border border-white rounded my-4 table-responsive">
            <div class="text-center my-3">
                <h1>Admin dashboard</h1>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-sm">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">Image</th>
                        <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">City</th>
                        <th scope="col">State</th>
                        <th scope="col">Email</th>
                        <th scope="col">ICON</th>
                        
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {displaylist}
                {displaylistf}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </section>
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You've already done that check when you check "gender=male" or "gender=female" so you can simply render a male/female icon in each mapping in the last column. Or are you rather looking for a way to do sorting/filter/mapping *once* so your code is more **DRY**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think conditional rendering might help you here.
For example:

```
<img src={User.gender === "male" ? 'some male image src in string' : 'some female image source in string' alt={User.gender} />
```